# My radio buttons, created with javascript, are not showing up

Tags: javascript, forms, google-cloud-firestore, radio-button, materialize

I am using firebase cloud firestore to hold several candidates' names in an election. I am trying to use JavaScript to create a form that shows each candidates' name in radio buttons. I have the script connected to my form, but the radio buttons don't show. It shows the name, but not the button. The form is in a popup modal. There are no errors in the console. [image]

Here is my code:

```
    const splCanList = document.querySelector('#SPLInput');
const setupSPLCans = (data) => {
  let html = '';
  if (data.length) {
    data.forEach(doc => {
        const SPLCan = doc.data();
        const li = `
          <input type="radio" name="SplElection" id="${SPLCan.name}" value="${SPLCan.name}" style="display:block;">${SPLCan.name}
          <br>
        `;
        html += li
    });
    splCanList.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
      splCanList.innerHTML = html;
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you send a demo please?

Comment: What is a demo?

Comment: check jsFiddle website and paste there the piece of code u mentioned with html and css as it is

Comment: Are there any console errors? `html` isn't defined in your `else`

Comment: There are no console errors. I have added data to the database already, so data.length is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of missing pieces here but from what I can tell this should work.

You didn't execute the `setupSPLCans` function anywhere and I had to fill in the gaps what the `data` shape is.

But what I did change that may have been bugs in your code is:

- I moved the `html` declaration up one block so that's accessible to your else clause
- The material CSS you used comes with radios being hidden automatically. I added some CSS to counter that

```js
const splCanList = document.querySelector('#SPLInput');
const setupSPLCans = (data) => {
  let html = '';  // <-- moved this up a line
  if (data.length) {
    data.forEach(doc => {
        const SPLCan = doc.data();
        const li = `
          <input type="radio" name="${SPLCan.name}" id="${SPLCan.name}" value="${SPLCan.name}" style="display:block;">${SPLCan.name}
          <br>
        `;
        html += li
    });
    splCanList.innerHTML = html;
  } else {
      splCanList.innerHTML = html;
  };
};

setupSPLCans([ // <-- made some assumptions based on your code
  {
    data: () => ({ name: 'name1' }),
  },
  {
    data: () => ({ name: 'name2' }),
  },
]);
```

```css
#SPLInput [type="radio"]:not(:checked), [type="radio"]:checked {
    position: static;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: initial;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div id="SPLInput"></div>
```

Comment: Also, radio buttons' name should be the same for every `input` in a "group" to act as radio buttons. But as you mentioned, _a lot of missing pieces_...

Comment: Actually, I did execute the function in a different file. Sorry about the confusion. Also, the data thing and moving html const up didn't work, it still doesn't show the radio buttons. I would like to not have it set to exactly 2 buttons, because there might be 3 or 4 also, it just depends and it will change over time.

Comment: I can't help you. This answer shows that it works. It's up to you to create a re-producible example that shows the bug...

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros in their code they made `id` and `name` the same. So it can't be the same... `id`s have to be unique... There is a LOT wrong here... ;)

Comment: I have edited my code so that the name is the same for each button. The Id will be different, becuase it gets a field from the database, and that field is different for each document. For my css, I am using materialize css. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css

Comment: If there is no error on the page and you run the above code it has to be a CSS issue...

Comment: @Anonoymous I have edited my answer to include your CSS which came with an override for radios to be invisible

Comment: Of course you can. Just like I showed you above. Add the additional CSS. Inline it if you want to. Note that I did include the material CSS in my example